# Installing and word docs etc

Tags: installation

Looking at installing Ubuntu but need some more info. If i install it does it remove my Windows 7 programme or can swap from one to the other?

Will i be able to use the programmes already installed on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should Check out [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer), Download the 12.04 isntaller because it will let you install it inside windows and try it natively out without irreparable changes.

but yes you can boot into each OS.

You will not be able to use programs written for windows (office etc) right off the bat in ubuntu. Check out Play on linux in the software center. It lets you run windows apps on scripts. if you have any other questions lemme know!